# gz или zip для данных в памяти

Tags: c

В одном проекте у меня мало места на флешке с которой происходит загрузка. Надо распаковать данные в памяти (файловой системы нет). Попробовал tinf, но получаю ошибку входных данных (Чем надо упаковать данные для распаковки через tinf?). Какие еще библиотеки можно использовать?

[tinf](https://github.com/jibsen/tinf), вызов функции tinf_uncompress возвращает TINF_DATA_ERROR (input error). Данные для функции сделал стандартным gz.

Comment: "но получаю ошибку" Какую? Приводите, пожалуйста, больше подробностей в вопросе. Хорошо бы добавить ещё ссылки на используемые решения.

Comment: Что у вас за данные хотя бы? Для каких-то данных и элементарного `RLE` будет достаточно, ну и реализаций `LZ77` полно на любых языках, думаю https://habr.com/ru/post/141827/

Comment: `tinf_uncompress` разжимает голый deflate, `tinf_gzip_uncompress` — gzip, `tinf_zlib_uncompress` — zlib... под капотом во всех случаях используется используется один и тот же алгоритм, но у gzip и в zlib есть дополнительные хедеры и футтеры... для данных сжатых `gz`, соответственно нужно использовать `tinf_gzip_uncompress()`

Comment: Согласен, данные такие, что жмутся прекрасно (в основном, нули, много повторов). Спасибо, поищу.